# Error db: migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, openproject

After migrating the database to the new server from my application, when I run the command `RAILS_ENV = production rake db: migrate`, got the following error:

```
==  AggregatedGlobalRolesMigrations: migrating ================================
-- add_column(:roles, :type, :string, {:limit=>30, :default=>"Role"})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'type': ALTER TABLE `roles` ADD `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT 'Role'/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:213:in `execute'
/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:461:in `add_column' ..........
```

Has anyone had similar problems and can help?

Comment: `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'type': ALTER TABLE roles ADD type varchar(30) DEFAULT` which means the type column already exists in the table

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you already have a column `type`

`type` is used in ActiveRecord for STI... you could try using a different column name, say `type_of`, and see if that sorts it.